# Find consecutive days called off using R

Tags: r, days

I am looking at making a scorecard for the attendance of my employees and I need help calculating the score. My condition is if the employee calls off a day it is -1 point however if they call off multiple days in a row it is still just -1 point.

For example:

```
employee   workdate    reason 
employee1  7/7/19      CAOF
employee1  7/19/19      CAOF
employee1  8/30/19      PUL 
employee1 10/02/19      CAOF 
employee1  10/9/19      CAOF 
employee1  10/10/19      CAOF
```

(picture of the what the data actually looks like)

[image: Snippet of Data]

So with this data I would see that employee 1 called off (reason CAOF) 5 days in this time period. However the last time he called off two consecutive days so that would only count as 1 point against him. So he would be -4 points for this time period.

I only have simple R knowledge but am trying to learn can anyone help me get this started?

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a `diff` across dates (assumed *sorted*), you can then filter out those below a threshold. For instance,

```r
dat$workdate <- as.Date(dat$workdate, "%m/%d/%y")
dat$datediff <- ave(as.integer(dat$workdate), dat$employee, FUN = function(z) c(Inf, diff(z)))
dat
#    employee   workdate reason datediff
# 1 employee1 2019-07-07   CAOF      Inf
# 2 employee1 2019-07-19   CAOF       12
# 3 employee1 2019-08-30    PUL       42
# 4 employee1 2019-10-02   CAOF       33
# 5 employee1 2019-10-09   CAOF        7
# 6 employee1 2019-10-10   CAOF        1
```

Or you can use `ave` just to generate a logical variable:

```r
dat$usereason <- ave(as.integer(dat$workdate), dat$employee, FUN = function(z) c(TRUE, diff(z) > 1))
dat
#    employee   workdate reason datediff usereason
# 1 employee1 2019-07-07   CAOF      Inf         1
# 2 employee1 2019-07-19   CAOF       12         1
# 3 employee1 2019-08-30    PUL       42         1
# 4 employee1 2019-10-02   CAOF       33         1
# 5 employee1 2019-10-09   CAOF        7         1
# 6 employee1 2019-10-10   CAOF        1         0
```

Note that `ave` forces the output to be the same class as its `x=` argument, so we can't return a literal `TRUE`/`FALSE` here (that I know of) without reclassing externally.

---

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(employee = c("employee1", "employee1", "employee1", "employee1", "employee1", "employee1"), workdate = c("7/7/19", "7/19/19", "8/30/19", "10/02/19", "10/9/19", "10/10/19"), reason = c("CAOF", "CAOF", "PUL", "CAOF", "CAOF", "CAOF")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I think OP doesn't want to count rows with `reason != 'CAOF'`

Comment: Both approaches permit follow-on filtering before counting, this technique just adds a field that hints at "ignore this row".

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
library (dplyr) 
df %>% filter(reason == 'CAOF')  %>% group_by(employee)  %>% mutate(d = workdate - lag(workdate, .default = as.Date("1900-01-01")) %>% filter(d>1) %>% summarise (score = sum(d))
```

Assuming your dates are arranged else arrange before mutate